# Wrong "Generated server url" in springdoc-openapi-ui (Swagger UI) deployed behind proxy

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

Spring Boot 2.2 application with springdoc-openapi-ui (Swagger UI) runs HTTP port.
The application is deployed to Kubernetes with Ingress routing HTTPS requests from outside the cluster to the service.

In this case Swagger UI available at `https://example.com/api/swagger-ui.html` has wrong "Generated server url" - `http://example.com/api`. While it should be `https://example.com/api`.

While Swagger UI is accessed by HTTPS, the generated server URL still uses HTTP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`springdoc-openapi` FAQ has a section [How can I deploy the Doploy `springdoc-openapi-ui`, behind a reverse proxy?](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy).

The FAQ section can be extended.

Make sure X-Forwarded headers are sent by your proxy (`X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and others).

If you are using Undertow (`spring-boot-starter-undertow`), set property `server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE` to make a Web server natively handle X-Forwarded headers. Also, consider switching to Undertow if you are not using it.

If you are using Tomcat (`spring-boot-starter-tomcat`), set property `server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE` and make sure to list IP addresses of all internal proxies to trust in the property `server.tomcat.internal-proxies=192\\.168\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}`. By default, IP addresses in 10/8, 192.168/16, 169.254/16 and 127/8 are trusted.

Alternatively, for Tomcat set property `server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK`.

Useful links:

- [Running Behind a Front-end Proxy Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server)
- [Customize Tomcat’s Proxy Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server)
- [ServerProperties.ForwardHeadersStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.ForwardHeadersStrategy.html)

Comment: the link to the FAQ is broken, the correct one is https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: I am using `server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK`, but still can see generated url is `http`.

Comment: Even on setting the property to `FRAMEWORK` , I am still getting `http` in the generated server url

Answer (score 28):

I had same problem. Below worked for me.

```javascript
@OpenAPIDefinition( 
    servers = {
       @Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")
    }
) 
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This worked out-of-the-box for me, thanks! Although, I annotated a `@Configuration` bean/class, not the main application class. I like this solution because 1) it is independent from the Spring Boot backend used (Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow), 2) it doesn't have a hard coded URL, 3) it's a "no code" solution, i.e. has no logic to assemble something at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

If the accepted solution doesn't work for you then you can always set the url manually by defining a bean.

```java
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.setUrl("https://example.com/api");
    return new OpenAPI().servers(List.of(server));
}
```

And the url can be defined via a property and injected here.

Answer (score 8):

In case you have non-default context path

```java
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI openAPI(ServletContext servletContext) {
        Server server = new Server().url(servletContext.getContextPath());
        return new OpenAPI()
                .servers(List.of(server))
                // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it default to "/" using @Server annotation. This will make the swagger APIs use `https`

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.servers.Server;

@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")})
public class FormService implements ApplicationRunner {
....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below worked for me.

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")})
@SpringBootApplication
class App{
// ...
}
```

or

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")})
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfig {
@Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("App name")
                        .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
                        .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")));
    }
}
```

[Generated server url is HTTP - issue](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/726)