# springdoc-openapi-ui(Swagger UI) is appending :80 port to the base URL

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a spring boot application running on the `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.1` version and `springdoc-openapi-ui:1.2.32`. Swagger is working fine locally. The problem comes when I deploy the app inside Kubernetes cluster. That time spring doc open API is automatically redirecting to HTTP(:80) instead of HTTPS. If I remove :80 from the base URL then swagger-ui is coming up. Using the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625494/wrong-generated-server-url-in-springdoc-openapi-ui-swagger-ui-deployed-behin) I have changed the generated server URL, so my REST APIs are working fine now. But how to get rid of the :80 port getting appended in the base URL automatically? What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to the latest version of `springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.6` solved the problem.